Template argumente deduction with overloaded function
I have the following code and am trying to understand why, in the first call to fun(), the compiler chooses the template instead of the non-template overload void fun(const int*).
#include <iostream>
struct test
{
    void fun(const int*)
    {
        std::cout<<"const int * overload\n";
    }
    template<typename T>
    void fun(const T&)
    {
        std::cout<<"template"<<'\n';
    }
};

int main(){
    test t{};
    int * int_ptr;
    t.fun(int_ptr);
    const int * const_int_ptr;
    t.fun(const_int_ptr);
}


Because the template version wins in overload resolution as exact match given T deduced as int*.

When template is present in overload it becomes greedy and in practice it disables conversions. Here template version wins since invocation of regular function requires conversion from int * to const int * and template do not require any conversions - it just deduces perfectly matching type.

https://godbolt.org/z/Kbqr4bxr9

Summary : const matters

With a function like this...
template <class T>
void foo(T t) // ...

The type T is deduced from the value you pass, so it's always a perfect match for the type of the value you pass in all respects.
So, when the compiler has to select between that function template and a normal (non-template) function, the latter can only be selected if the parameter is also an perfect match for the type of the value being passed in all respects.
Any mismatch of any kind--even one so slight as a mismatch between int * and int const *--will be a a worse match than than the template provides, so the template will be the preferred selection.
